# How to rename file when using move_uploaded_file()?

Tags: php, forms, upload, rename

Problem: I can't rename my file no matter what method I find on any site. I always receive this error

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(CUSTOM/TestFile.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\CUSTOM\upload.php on line 7
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\XAMPP\tmp\php7AAB.tmp' to 'CUSTOM/TestFile.txt' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\CUSTOM\upload.php on line 7

If I don't try to rename the uploaded file, the upload is successful, however, the file is renamed to the folder name (In this case "CUSTOM")

CONTEXT:

Server: Localhost using XAMPP software

file_upload        = yes on php.ini

Folder Permissions = yes

Folder Exists      = yes

Form Action        = self

Form Method        = post

Form Enctype       = is used

May fortune be forever upon thee who finds a solution.

```
    <?php  

        $fname = $_FILES['file']['name'];  
        $ftemp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
        $location = "CUSTOM/";  

        move_uploaded_file($ftemp, $location.$fname);  

        ?>  

        <html>                     
        <body>             


        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
            <input type="file" name="file" ><br/>        
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File">        
        </form>        


    </body>        
    </html>
```

Comment: `failed to open stream: No such file or directory...` the file you are attempting to move is not where you think it is.

Comment: Have you tried `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location.$_FILES['file']['name']);`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not your issue:

> `Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\XAMPP\tmp\php7AAB.tmp'`

But this is:

> `to 'CUSTOM/TestFile.txt'`

Because of:

> `in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\CUSTOM\upload.php on line 7`

You're essentially trying to move your temporary file to **`CUSTOM/CUSTOM/TestFile.txt`**. Your upload script, which you should have mentioned, already resides in `CUSTOM`. Which thus is the current working directory. Therefore trying to write to a file with another ***relative*** path prefix of `CUSTOM/` will »double« the supposed target directory name.

Btw, the client-supplied `name` can be **anything** - even `index.php` or overwrite `upload.php` or perhaps even `../../boot.ini`. Don't just accept any user input. At least apply [`basename`](http://php.net/basename), whitelist when feasible, use a target folder distinct from where scripts reside, and disallow CGI/PHP execution per `.htaccess` etc.

Comment: May fortune forever be upon you. Now, that leads to my next question: How do you set the path relative to the site directory? Here are my paths for reference: <br/>

Site Dir    = "C:\XAMPP" 
Script Dir  = "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\SCRIPTS\upload.php"
Uploads Dir = "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\UPLOADS"